# Sql query Join/Where 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some issues with a query.

I currently have 3 tables:

```
BOOK
Book_Num
Title
Publisher_Code

AUTHOR
Author_Num
Author_Fname
Author_Lname

WROTE
Book_Code
Authour_Num
Sequence
```

I need a query that lists all of the Books written by John Steinbeck. Therefore I need to join tables, but I struggle with joins and am having some difficulty.

This is the query I have so far:

```
`SELECT W.BOOK_CODE, W.AUTHOR_NUM , B.TITLE, A.AUTHOR_LAST
    FROM WROTE W
    JOIN BOOK B ON W.BOOK_CODE = B.BOOK_CODE
    JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_LAST
    WHERE A.AUTHOR_LAST = "Steinbeck"
    ORDER BY A.AUTHOR_LAST;
`
```

It's currently just showing an empty set but that field is definitely there.

Comment: "struggle with joins and am having some difficulty" won't help you much.  Explain what's wrong with your query.  Does it give you error????  Does it give you no result???  Does it give you wrong result??? What's your expected result????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question was answered and I clearly stated what I wanted my results to be.

Comment: b.book_Code... I see no such column in the book table definition  Do you mean `B.Book_Num` on the first table join's on clause?  in addition A.Author_last should likely be `A.Author_Num` on the 2nd join's ON clause.

Comment: what does sequence do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_LAST
```

It should be

```
JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_NUM
```

Also, it looks like you are using `B.BOOK_CODE` WHEN YOU SHOULD BE USING `B.BOOK_NUM`

This should get it for you:

```
SELECT W.BOOK_CODE, W.AUTHOR_NUM , B.TITLE, A.AUTHOR_LAST
FROM WROTE W
JOIN BOOK B ON W.BOOK_CODE = B.BOOK_NUM
JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_NUM
WHERE A.AUTHOR_LAST = "Steinbeck"
ORDER BY A.AUTHOR_LAST;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `B.Book_Code` on the 1st join also be `b.Book_num` according tot the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with this line:

JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_LAST

You are joining the Author_Num from the wrote table to the Author_Last from the Author table.

Try this instead:
JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_NUM

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT W.BOOK_CODE, W.AUTHOR_NUM , B.TITLE, A.AUTHOR_LAST
FROM WROTE W
JOIN BOOK B ON W.BOOK_CODE = B.BOOK_CODE
JOIN AUTHOR A ON W.AUTHOR_NUM = A.AUTHOR_LAST --its wrong 
-- it must A.Author_Num
WHERE A.AUTHOR_LAST = "Steinbeck"
ORDER BY A.AUTHOR_LAST
```

You must relation with PK primary key and foreing key.

Comment: B.Book_Code doesn't exist either.  Should be B.Book_num I think.